# how to improve the performance of streamwriter

Tags: c#, .net

I'm working on smart device with compact framework 3.0
I'm using streamwriter class to write data on file. My file size is 256KB but It's taking almost 60 seconds to save the file.

here is my code:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(tmppath, true))
{
    sw.AutoFlush = true;

    sw.WriteLine(_RM.GetString("Key"));

    sw.WriteLine(RM.GetString("Key1") + "\t" + Controller.Time.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:ss"));

    sw.WriteLine(RM.GetString("Name") + "\t" + Controller.SystemName);
    sw.WriteLine(RM.GetString("SystemName") + "\t" + stCtrlName);
    sw.WriteLine(RM.GetString("SystemId") + "\t" + stCtrlId);

    sw.WriteLine();

    Controller.GetVersion(out major, out minor, out revision, out build);
    sw.WriteLine(RM.GetString("build") + string.Format("\t{0}.{1}.{2}", major, minor, build));

    sw.WriteLine(OptionsSection(SystemInfo.ModuleType.Control));
    sw.WriteLine();


    sw.WriteLine(OptionsSection(SystemInfo.ModuleType.Drive));
    sw.WriteLine();


    sw.WriteLine(OptionsSection1());


    string header = FormatMsg(stSeqNo, stType, stDomain, stId, stTitle, stDate, RM.GetString("Key2"), stArgs);

    using (Log evLog = new Log(Log.DomainType.All))
    {
        sw.WriteLine();

        // {0} log messages
        string domain = string.Format(RM.GetString("STBEVT_TXT_LOGFILENEWDOMAIN"), Log.GetEventLogDescription(Log.DomainType.All));
        sw.WriteLine(domain);

        // Write column headings
        sw.WriteLine(header);

        string str = string.Empty;

        foreach (EventMessage em in evLog.GetEvents())
        {
            sw.WriteLine(FormatMsg(em.SequenceNumber, em));
        }
    }

    Log.DomainType domType = Log.DomainType.NoOfDomains;
    foreach (EventMessage em in allEvents)
    {
        if (_progressBar._pBar.Value >= _progressBar._pBar.Maximum)
        {
            _progressBar._pBar.Value = 0;
        }
        else
        {

            _progressBar._pBar.Value += 1;
        }
        if (em.Domain != domType)
        {
            sw.WriteLine();

            // {0} log messages
            string domain = string.Format(RM.GetString("STBEVT_TXT_LOGFILENEWDOMAIN"), Log.GetLogDescription(em.Domain));
            sw.WriteLine(domain);

            // Write column headings
            sw.WriteLine(header);

            domType = em.Domain;
        }

        sw.WriteLine(FormatMsg(em.SequenceNumber, em));

    }
```

Please tell me how Can I improve performance such that It will take 10 to 15seconds to save 256KB data.

Comment: What is the current performance? Have you measured?

Comment: Yeah, Right now It's taking 60 seconds to save whole data(256KB)

Comment: Can you be sure its the StreamWriter? Can you run a profile in Visual Studio [Analyze -> Performance & Diagnostics]

Comment: Good. Now measure how long it takes to copy a 256KB file on the same disk. That will be a good goal.

Comment: I have observed that   foreach (EventMessage em in evLog.GetEvents())
        {
            sw.WriteLine(FormatMsg(em.SequenceNumber, em));
        }
FormatMsg() is taking almost 45 seconds to performing their operation. It's just converting data in descriptive manner.